# i want to delete the record from data base using php on which record i click

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to create a crud. 
i wrote php query to delete the fetched data . but i dont know what to write after ID= "" in Delete query. my code given below

index file

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>crud system</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php include 'connect.php';?>

    <form method="post" action="postdata.php">
    username:
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

postdata.php

```
//postdata.php
<?php 
mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("cannot to database");
mysql_select_db('users');

$name = $_POST['name'];
$sql="INSERT into add_data (name) values('$name')";
$query=mysql_query($sql);

if(!$query){

    echo"data entrance failed".mysql_error();
}
else{
    echo "data added successfully !";
}
?>
```

fetchint data select.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
include 'connect.php';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM add_data");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

echo $row["name"]."<a href=\"delete.php\">delete</a>"."<br/>";
 }
?>  

</body>
</html>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
include_once 'connect.php';  
mysql_query("DELETE FROM add_data WHERE **id=2"**);
header('location:select.php');

?>
```

now in delete file i dont want to write id=2 because it will only delete 2nd record i want to delete whatever i click on.

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In select.php

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
 {
    echo $row["name"].'<a href="delete.php?del_id='.$row["id"].'">Delete</a><br/>';
 }
```

In  delete.php

```
$del_id = '';
if(!empty($_GET['del_id']))
{
    $del_id = $_GET['del_id'];
    include_once 'connect.php';  
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM add_data WHERE id = '$del_id' ");
    header('location:select.php');
}
```

Comment: very nice thank you. it is working, can u explain this code for me.

Comment: yeah sure !! just wait a moment I'll be back in few minutes.. @coder

Comment: In your select.php file we made an link with user id in query string, each link has unique user id which is passed in url when delete link is clicked and for getting that user id in delete.php file we use PHP `$_GET[]` method [read more about get](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp), `$_GET['del_id']` give us id to be deleted

Comment: `?` is used to separate the page url and  appended information that is sent along with url, `http://www.test.com/index.htm?name1=value1&name2=value2` as you can see in this url `http://www.test.com/index.htm` is the requested url and this is `name1=value1&name2=value2` the information sent with url

Comment: `?` is used to separate url and information and `&` is for distinguishing information parameters

Comment: @coder  glad to help you ;) up vote my answer if it is helpful for you :)

Comment: yeah !! It's  okay Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

Provide the id to the delete.php script and retrieve it with $_GET then perform your delete with a where clause using the retrieved id

```
echo $row["name"]."<a href=\"delete.php?id=".$row["id"]."\">delete</a>"."<br/>";
```

And in delete.php

$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id']) : 0;

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\easy\delete.php on line 3

Comment: update this line $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : 0;